# what is nonBlockingRedelivery in ActiveMQConnectionFactory

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I couldnt find a reference doc or explanation of nonBlockingRedelivery of ActivemqConnectionFactory. Please tell the meaning of this or some link to some docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The nonBlockingRedelivery options controls whether on a Rollback of the session the messages that were previously delivered and will be re-delivered should block the delivery of new incoming messages or should new messages be allowed to be intermingled with the rolled back messages.  You can see the JIRA issue that requested this feature [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-1853).

You should be careful with this option as it can lead to out of order delivery of messages on rollback as the rolled back messages can have new messages dispatched to your consumer instead of being held until the older messages are all re-dispatched.

Comment: Is `nonBlockingRedelivery` only applicable to Rollback of the session?  The JIRA in which you implemented this ([AMQ-1853](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-1853)) doesn't make any mention of rollback, so I expected you'd also get this behavior when a message fails delivery in a non-transactional environment.  Am I misunderstanding the JIRA?